# How to hook CopyTextureRegion with Minhook

Tags: c++, directx, hook

Im trying to hook the [ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::CopyTextureRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12graphicscommandlist-copytextureregion) method with [MinHook](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra) but the problem is that the method is inside ID3D12GraphicsCommandList which makes it hard to hook.

Here is my current approach which unfortunatley is 0

```
// not working, CopyTextureRegionHook is 0
auto CopyTextureRegionHook = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("d3d12.dll"), "CopyTextureRegion");
MH_CreateHook(reinterpret_cast<void**>(CopyTextureRegionHook), &HK_CopyTextureRegion, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&oCopyTextureRegion));
MH_EnableHook(CopyTextureRegionHook);
```

Hooking methods like D3D12CreateDevice, D3D12CoreRegisterLayers.. work because they are not in a interface like ID3D12GraphicsCommandList

**How would I properly hook CopyTextureRegion?**

Comment: https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/222-intercepting-com-calls

Comment: I dont really know how to apply that to the CopyTextureRegionHook.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're dealing with an interface, you won't be able to hook the function directly in memory since it's dependent on the pointer to the interface. In which case you have to utilize a technique called VMT(Virtual Method Table) hooking. In order to achieve this, you'll need to be able to retrieve the pointer to the interface in memory, then locate the virtual method table index(offset) of the function pointer. Which then you'll have to overwrite with your own function address. Your hooked function will have to comply with the calling convention of the original.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try this tomorrow and let you know how it went.